# YouTube Data API v3 Request Only

Tags: javascript, request, youtube-data-api

I just want to request my **viewCount**, **subscriberCount** and **videoCount**. All these three things are listed when I open [this](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCjbKGThd8c8bNTjmcEw9rtw&key=MY_API_KEY) url in my browser.

I am working with JavaScript. All I want to do now is *save* this three variables and *display* them on my website. No authentication is needed.

I tried a lot of code examples but it never worked. I have no idea how this works. Please help me!

Comment: you can use axios library. It does some simple async fetching of data and returns json object. Check out their official documentation.
Also, do you want to do data fetching in plain JavaScript or in some framework/library?

Comment: I used axios and its working now, thank you. Is there any danger when someone looks at the source code of my website and sees my API key?

Comment: Yes, there is. that is why you should keep it hidden inside some environment variable or try to hide it in some other way... If my previous comment was helpful, I would appreciate if you can upvote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look in the reason of the invalid request it tells you that a key is needed.
In fact, as almost all the google API services nowadays, you need to register your application and get an API key that will replace the value of the parameter key in your url (Now it is set as a demonstration as `key=MY_API_KEY`).
[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) is the link for the guide to app google registration.
Hope this answer can be useful to you.